# laravel is unable to get primericons from localhost

Tags: reactjs, laravel-8, laravel-mix, primeicons

I wanted to integrate primereact / primeicons in my Laravel project. But having a bit of a strange error.

The error shows in the console when I run the project:

```
http://localhost/fonts/vendor/primeicons/primeicons.woff?e61f3495a7ecd3d571a4c9a98797e955 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the app.scss file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

//primereact
@import 'primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';
@import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
@import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

these primereact library also included in resources/js/src/Entryfile/Main.js
but still not working

here is the package.json file

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"keywords": [
    "reactjs",
    "filter",
    "sort",
    "DataTables",
    "jQuery",
    "table",
    "DataTables"
],
"files": [
    "js/*/.js"
],
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.2.0",
    "antd": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-sticky-kit": "^1.1.3",
    "line-awesome": "^1.3.0",
    "maskedinput": "^3.3.11",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primereact": "^6.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rc-footer": "^0.6.6",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-countdown-circle-timer": "^3.0.9",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.9.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-loading-ui": "^1.2.3",
    "react-owl-carousel": "^2.3.1",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-scrollspy-nav": "^1.2.4",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.7",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "react-sticky-box": "^0.9.3",
    "react-summernote": "^2.0.2",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "secure-ls": "^1.2.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sticky-kit": "^1.1.3",
    "sticky-sidebar": "^3.3.1",
    "theia-sticky-sidebar": "^1.7.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "csv-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
},
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "child_process": false
}
```

}